# How to make a new list with a property of an Map which is in another list

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Imagine that I have a `List<Map<String,Object>>`:

```
[{'id':1,'name':'xyz'},{'id':2,'name':'abc'},{'id':3,'name':'pqr'}]
```

And I need to generate another list including the name in the above list:

```
List<String>
```

Avoiding using a loop, is it possible to achieve this by using java stream api?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<String> names = list.stream()
                         .map(i -> i.get("name").toString())
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since `i.get("name").toString()` might produce a NPE, it's smart to filter out maps that don't contain the key `"name"`:

```
List<String> names = list.stream()
                         .filter(i -> i.containsKey("name"))
                         .map(i -> i.get("name").toString())
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<String> names = list.stream()
                         .map(i -> i.get("name"))
                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                         .map(Object::toString)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: how about `i.getOrDefault(i,"other")`

Comment: @HadiJ then we would have to filter `"other"`s out of the result, right?

Comment: Maybe `map(i -> i.get("name")).filter(name -> name != null).map(name -> name.toString())` in order to prevent `containsKey`?

Comment: We don't know what kind of map we have. A `containsKey`could be expensive. What you think? On the other hand there could be an etnry with a key `"name"` but OP should clearify if the corresponding value might be `null` (it don't seems so).

Comment: I think that maybe it's not that `containsKey` is wrong, but that using `containsKey` and then immediately `get` means 2 lookups per present key in the map, while you might perfectly have only 1 lookup with `get` and then `!= null`.

Comment: Yes ... this is why I said to _prevent_ `containsKey`.

Comment: `toString()` in the first case is not required

Comment: @TheScientificMethod `map(i -> i.get("name"))` gives a `Stream<Object>` according to OP's structure `List<Map<String,Object>>`